# Using kaptcha with JSF

Tags: jsf, captcha

I'm trying to use http://code.google.com/p/kaptcha/ which looks like a very easy way to include CAPTCHA. My demo app is JSF and although [the instructions are simple](http://code.google.com/p/kaptcha/wiki/HowToUse) for JSP, I don't know how to use them in JSF. How do I translate this in JSF?

> In your code that manages the submit action:
>
> `String kaptchaExpected = (String)request.getSession()
>       .getAttribute(com.google.code.kaptcha.Constants.KAPTCHA_SESSION_KEY);
>   String kaptchaReceived = request.getParameter("kaptcha");`
>
> `if (kaptchaReceived == null || !kaptchaReceived.equalsIgnoreCase(kaptchaExpected))
>   {
>       setError("kaptcha", "Invalid validation code.");
>   }`

I tried putting it in my:

```
public String button1_action() {
    // TODO: Process the action. 
    return "success";
}
```

but it doesn't understand the request object :(

Answer (score 1):

This equivalent JSF action should do it:

```
  // bind to <h:inputText value="#{thisbean.kaptchaReceived}" />
  private String kaptchaReceived;

  public String getKaptchaReceived() {
    return kaptchaReceived;
  }

  public void setKaptchaReceived(String kaptcha) {
    kaptchaReceived = kaptcha;
  }

  public String button1_action() {
    if (kaptchaReceived != null) {
      FacesContext context = FacesContext
          .getCurrentInstance();
      ExternalContext ext = context.getExternalContext();
      Map<String, Object> session = ext.getSessionMap();
      String kaptchaExpected = session
          .get(com.google.code.kaptcha.Constants.KAPTCHA_SESSION_KEY);
      if (kaptchaReceived.equalsIgnoreCase(kaptchaExpected)) {
        return "success";
      }
    }
    return "problem";
  }
```

This assumes that you want to use [h:inputText](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/tlddocs/h/inputText.html) and [h:graphicImage](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/tlddocs/h/graphicImage.html) in your JSF view instead of HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing validator is another easy way to validate the kaptcha.

```
<h:inputText id="kaptcha" autocomplete="off" required="true">
     <f:validator validatorId="kaptchaValidator" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="kaptcha" styleClass="errorMessage"/>
```

--- Validator ---

```
public class KaptchaValidator implements Validator {

@Override
public void validate(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object value) throws ValidatorException {

HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(true);

        String kaptchaExpected = (String) session.getAttribute(com.google.code.kaptcha.Constants.KAPTCHA_SESSION_KEY);

        String kaptchaReceived = (String) value;

        if (kaptchaReceived == null || !kaptchaReceived.equalsIgnoreCase(kaptchaExpected)) {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();

            message.setDetail("Invalid Security Code.");
            message.setSummary("Invalid security code.");
            message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);

            throw new ValidatorException(message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the request object from the JSF External Context, which is accessible from the FacesContext, using the following code:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
```

---

**Edit** (thanks to [McDowell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/304/mcdowell)) :

Another way is to use the `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()` method to access the request parameters...

Comment: An alternative is to use ExternalContext.getRequestParameterMap() to avoid importing the servlet API.